# How does it the geth ethereum platform to automatically connect to the nodes that are in the main network of Ethereum?

Tags: p2p, blockchain, ethereum, go-ethereum

I have tried to make connection between several nodes in my private network, but I do it with a direction enode, but Ethereum network does it without knowing my address enode, I want to know what kind of p2p communication protocols used so that all nodes are communicate with each other, and if that code is free.

Comment: See this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7743/what-are-the-peer-discovery-mechanisms-involved-in-ethereum where there's a description of the peer to peer mechanism used by the ethereum network.

Answer (score 0):

1. when start the geth your need some config enode to connect to
2. by using the p2p network(kad) discover function, geth will discovery other nodes.the discover function can be disable by using --nodsicovery command line arg.